# JavaMail via Outlook on remote environment

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I send letters with help of JavaMail Api via outlook server. I use corporate exchange's ip to send letters:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "my.corporate.host");
```

It works well on localhost, BUT it doesn't work on remote environment, which is located in another country.

*What can be the problem?*

*P.S.* I can send emails from test environment via gmail service. It seems that problem is in External_Server + Corporate_Exchange server

Comment: Most of the corporate servers don't allow mails from the remote environment due to the fact that it will be a breach. And they use mostly the domain authentication techniques by adding the hotsname in Active Directory

Comment: @Harsha This explains a lot. More details (about how to make it work), please.

Comment: I had worked only with the case of remote mailing servers not responding to the local mail triggering scripts but not the reverse way

Comment: You need to provide more details than "it doesn't work".  Are you getting an exception?  Are you getting a "mailer-daemon" error message?  Is the mail just never being delivered?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple.

I set path to mail resources (templates/ images) as project's path, but after packaging and deploying to server these paths are changed. So the reason, i suppose, is ResourceNotFoundException.

One more proof why server app without logging shouldn't exist.